# Knockout.js: Determine visibility based on compared properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a Knockout view model that maintains three things: a list of default properties, a list of entities, and a list of entity classes. The entity classes each have a subset of the available entities and a separate list of properties that overwrite the default properties.

What I'm trying to do is highlight cases where the entity class has a property that overwrites the corresponding default without changing it -- a so-called 'bad overwrite'. I am new to Knockout and am unable to think of a way to do this. The issue is that it needs to be a computed property (as the table updates frequently, and the data is retrieved from a server) based on comparing a value that's deep in the viewmodel with one that's more shallow. The mapping looks like this:

```
function Master() //(view model)
{
    var self = this;
    self.EntityClasses = ko.observableArray();
    self.DefaultProperties = ko.observableArray();
    self.Entites = ko.observableArray();
}

function EntityClass()
{
    var self = this;
    self.Properties = ko.observableArray();
}
```

And I'm looking to compare a property that's in a given entity with the properties in the default properties list in order to determine if there are overwriting properties that are not different. The comparison would be where  is below:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: EntityClasses">
  <span data-bind="if: PropertiesVisible">
    <h3><span data-bind="text: EntityClassName"></span> Properties</h3>
    <table>
    <tr><th>Property ID</th><th>Key</th><th>Value</th><th>Flags</th></tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Properties"> <!-- in that entity class -->
      <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: PropertyID"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Key"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Value"></td>
        <td>
          <span data-bind="if: <SOME BOOLEAN>"> <!-- if equal to default -->
            <!-- Indicate bad overwrite -->
          </span>
        </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think we're going to need to see some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout includes so called [`computed obervables`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html), which do exactly what you need. You can create them with `ko.computed()`.
If you access other observables in the function passed to the computed observable, the computed will update automatically if the dependencies update.

```
function Master() //(view model)
{
    var self = this;
    self.EntityClasses = ko.observableArray();
    self.DefaultProperties = ko.observableArray();
    self.Entites = ko.observableArray();
    self.overwritingProperties = ko.computed(function(){
        //compare properties
        self.Entities.doSomething //<- when this observable updates (e.g. an entry is added), the computed observable is reevaluated automatically
        var result = true;
        return result;
    });
}
```

You can bind them like any other observable:

```
<span data-bind="if: overwritingProperties">
```